# One Time Deployment - I have Windows 7 install media on a USB key. How can I tell if it contains install images for 32 bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

One Time Deployment - I have Windows 7 install media on a USB key. How can I tell if it contains install images for 32 bit?

imagex /info doesn't tell me anything about the architecture, other than this line: `<ARCH>9</ARCH>`. I can't find a file explaining which it is, nor can I tell what ARCH 9 is :)

Thanks for your help.

Also asked here: https://serverfault.com/questions/119928/one-time-deployment-i-have-windows-7-install-media-on-a-usb-key-how-can-i-tell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the autorun.inf file if it is 32bit it will read as follows

> [Autorun]
>
> open=setup.exe
>
> icon=setup.exe,0

If it is 64bit

> [AutoRun.Amd64]
>
> open=setup.exe
>
> icon=setup.exe,0
>
> [AutoRun]
>
> open=sources\sperr32.exe x64
>
> icon=sources\sperr32.exe,0

Comment: Thanks, but isn't also possible to have 32 bit images to deploy in the latter case?